# Why getting Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority?

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl

I've developed a windows service with C#.NET and calling a Java web service from my windows service. The web service is certificate protected so my client has provided me with the certificate. I've installed the certificate using MMC.EXE to Root, Personal and Trusted People section but getting the following error while trying to communicate with their API.

> Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority 'pmtest.xxxxxx.ua:9192'.
>   inner exception : The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Here is my code for calling the method in their web service.

```
  try
   {
      System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate { return true; };
     resp = (EBMType)wsClient.InvokeMember(this.remoteMethodName, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, this.privatMoney, new object[] { this.requestObject }); //Here I'm getting error
    }
  catch (System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException e)
    {
              System.ServiceModel.FaultException<FaultType> ex = (System.ServiceModel.FaultException<FaultType>)e.InnerException;
                    throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("PrivatMoney error occurred. Message: {0}, Code: {1}", ex.Detail.FaultNotification.FaultMessage.Text, ex.Detail.FaultNotification.FaultMessage.Code));
     }
```

May I please know what to do in this situation as I'm quite new in this field. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may need to provide proxy credentials.

Comment: I don't know how to provide proxy credentials. May I please know how to do that?

Comment: It is available over internet. You can try searching. For a head start, try this link and see if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859224/calling-a-webservice-from-behind-a-proxy-server

Comment: thank you for the suggestion I've checked this. But we are not using a proxy server to communicate. Also, their web service is not available using browser. But I can use their functions in SOAPUI.

Comment: did you find a solution ?